# Java process gets stuck

Tags: java

I have to make a Java Program to use [CCCC](http://sarnold.github.io/cccc/CCCC_User_Guide.html) tool over all the code files in a software project.

This is my code:

```
public class Main {
public static void listfiles(String path) {
    File directory = new File(path);
    //get all the files from a directory
    if(directory.exists()) {
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList){

            if (file.isFile()){
                String filepath = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(path.length() + 1);

                if(filepath.contains(".c")
                        || filepath.contains(".cpp")
                        || filepath.contains(".cc")
                        || filepath.contains(".java")) {
                    System.out.println(filepath);

                    try {
                        String[] cmd = { "cccc.exe", file.getAbsolutePath()};
                        System.out.println("CCCC Started! " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                        p.waitFor();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else if (file.isDirectory()){
                listfiles(file.getAbsolutePath());    // file.getName() for just file names
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    listfiles("C:/proj/platform_packages_apps_contacts");
}
```

As you can see in the code, I am scanning the directory for C, C++ and Java files and calling CCCC over each file. But the process gets stuck after some files. The tool works normally when run from command line over the same file but gets stuck over some file when run using Java. This is my output. This shows only one file, but there are many more files and it is just stuck like this.

`ActionBarAdapter.java
CCCC Started! C:\proj\platform_packages_apps_contacts\src\com\android\contacts\activities\ActionBarAdapter.java`

Please tell where I'm doing wrong and if possible suggest a better way of doing it.

Comment: You need to continuously read the other processes stdout and stderr.

Comment: Also, how many folders/subfolders and total file count do you have on `C:/proj/platform_packages_apps_contacts`, you might be reaching some recursive overflow.

Comment: It was because of buffer overflow. Now it is solved. Thanks everyone. :)